# Web 2.0 online network diagram image generator

Tags: networking, web

Does any web 2.0 online network diagram generators exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but are you wanting for it to generate the diagram for you?  That I haven't seen.  If you just want to create network diagrams online (without visio, or something) try Gliffy: http://www.gliffy.com

Comment: Gliffy isnt free.  I'm looking for something totally free (and it can have very basic features).  I dont need the bells and whistles at all... in fact, i dont want them.

Answer (score 0):

When writing commercial proposals, I am doing most of the network diagrams with Cacoo.

They have a reasonably nice+uniform collection of network/IT icons.

Here is the last one I created (more formal/technical drawings are possible too):

[image]

Also this kind of network sequence diagrams:

[image]

Cacoo has a restriction: only 20 free diagrams, but time-unlimited.

Answer (score -1):

NodeSystems will generate an interactive online diagram automatically:

Check out the online demo:
http://www.nodesystems.org/demo/